# OpentTok (iOS) How to subscribe to hasAudio stream changes

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

I need a possibility in the TokBox iOS SDK to find out if a subscribed stream has audio dynamically / via an event. ([`OTStream.hasAudio`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTStream.html#//api/name/hasAudio))

[`OTSubscriberDelegate`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSubscriberKitDelegate.html) provides callbacks for the subscribed video state `subscriberVideoEnabled/Disabled` but I can't find anything for audio.

- The JS SDK provides the [`StreamPropertyChangedEvent`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/StreamPropertyChangedEvent.html) for this.
- The Android SDK provides the [`StreamPropertiesListener`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.StreamPropertiesListener.html) for this.
- iOS seems to be the only platform that doesn't have a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

For the iOS SDK, we don't provide a delegate for stream property changes, but you can implement [key value observing(KVO)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notifications/nskeyvalueobserving?changes=_1) to check if the observed stream property has changed.

In the example below, I added an observer for the `hasAudio` stream property and the observer will print the old and new values whenever it changes.

```
 func session(_ session: OTSession, streamCreated stream: OTStream) {
   let hasAudioObservation: NSKeyValueObservation = stream.observe(\.hasAudio, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
     guard let oldValue = change.oldValue else { return }
     guard let newValue = change.newValue else { return }
     print("Old stream value: \(oldValue)")
     print("New stream value: \(newValue)")
}
```

Comment: Do you plan on updating this any time soon? Using KVO for this seems to be overkill. Why not a closure or delegate?