# can we pause video call with toxbox / OpenTok in iOS

Tags: ios, video-streaming, opentok

I am creating demo with `OpenTok` library. It is created and working fine so far.

Now I want to implement hold / pause feature in video call. But I can't find direct method to put call on hold or we can say pause video call in between.

Can we put video call on hold ? If yes, then how ?

Has anyone idea about that ?

I have refered this link : [Putting a video call on hold with OpenTok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218330/putting-a-video-call-on-hold-with-opentok) But it is for .js

**Update : 1**

I have created properties for required Objects :

```
var otSession: OTSession!
var otPublisher: OTPublisher!
var otSubscriber: OTSubscriber!
```

And did required code for connecting session and put delegate methods.

Now on button click I want to pause video call, for that :

```
@IBAction func pauseVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if otPublisher != nil {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        otPublisher?.publishVideo = !(otPublisher?.publishVideo)!
    }

    if sender.isSelected {
        self.lblPause.text = "Call paused..!!"
        self.lblPause.isHidden = false
        otSubscriber.view?.isHidden = true
        otSubscriber.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    } else {
        self.lblPause.isHidden = true
        otSubscriber.view?.isHidden = false
        otSubscriber.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

It's working fine, But now on the other hand how they know that on first end video call put on hold ?

If one end it is on hold, then other side as well we have to hide video view and make it black. Other end may be admin panel or mobile app.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The OpenTok iOS SDK also allows you to stop publishing `audio` and `video` using [`publishAudio`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTPublisherKit.html#//api/name/publishAudio) and [`publishVideo`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTPublisherKit.html#//api/name/publishVideo) properties of the [`Publisher`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTPublisherKit.html) Object. You can change these properties at any time after you've created the `Publisher`.

This would not necessarily put the [`Session`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTSession.html) on hold, but it would stop sending video and audio to the other participants. You would have to create your own custom logic where you would show a message or icon indicating that the session is on hold when audio and video are not being published.

**Update 1(based on changes in the question):**

You can implement [key value observing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notifications/nskeyvalueobserving?changes=_1) to see if a stream property (i.e video or audio) have changed. This implementation will allow you to see when someone stops or starts publishing video. For a sample implementation, please see [OpentTok (iOS) How to subscribe to hasAudio stream changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157636/openttok-ios-how-to-subscribe-to-hasaudio-stream-changes/51158285#51158285).

Comment: Hi @VRAwesome, I updated my answer based on the info you shared